# Can we assign values to interface and make request in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making call in getData method so i have to build object and assign value to interface that i have checking type, Can we assign values directly to interface before making call and use as param for http call ?

main.ts

```
public getData(args: IParams): Promise < any > {

    const request: any = {
        "data": {
            "appName": args.appName,
            "channelName": args.channelName
        }
    }
    return Promise.resolve(http.makeRequest(request));
}
```

IParams.interface.ts

```
export interface IParams {

    appName: string,
    channelname: string
}
```

Comment: No, you cant assign anything to an interface. However youcan assign everything you want to an object.

Comment: so you are saying i can assign values `data` dynamically ?

Comment: Yes why not?!? ...